# Move repository from one group to another in GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ce

Is it possible to move a GitLab repository from one group to another in GitLab?

For example, I have https://gitlab.com/my-user/my-repo. I'd like to move it to https://gitlab.com/my-group/another-group/my-repo.

Ideally, I'd like to keep all the issues associated with it.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Yes, you can move your GitLab project from one `namespace` to another.

`Your project` -> `Settings` -> `General` -> `Advanced`
[image]

Then, almost at the end of the list.

[`Transfer project`](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/06/30/feature-highlight-groups/#transferring-an-existing-project-into-a-group)
[image]

Comment: what role/rights do I need to transfer? I'm the owner of the project but I can see only "Housekeeping" and "Rename repository " no transfer. I use GitLab 11.9.6

Comment: the page says that repo owner can do the transfer, however as I wrote: me (repo owner) couldn't trasfer the project. I guess there are some rules/policie in repo groups (e.g. http://mygitlab.com/group/myOwnrepo)

Comment: You have to have the correct permissions in both the current and new locations.

Comment: that worked for me, but has a strange effect. After 'transfering' the project I can still push channges to the old remote repo. I did not have to update the local repository to point to the new remote one ?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the already accepted answer, if you are not seeing the target group

### Go to the group admin section of the TARGET account

`https://gitlab.com/groups/<GROUP_NAME>/-/group_members`

### Add your user and set permissions to at least `Maintainer` privileges

(create a new group if needed)

[image: maintainer privileges are required]

### Follow the rest of the instructions from the accepted answer

- sign into the account that owns the project
- go to advanced settings at `https://gitlab.com/<USER_NAME>/<PROJECT_NAME>/edit`
  or click `Your project` -> `Settings` -> `General` -> `Advanced`
- Select the group from the drop-down

Answer (score 0):

Note at, with [GitLab 15.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/10/22/gitlab-15-5-released/#api-endpoint-to-get-project-transfer-locations) (October 2022), you now have:

> ### API endpoint to get project transfer locations
>
> We added a new Projects API endpoint that returns a list of groups to which you can transfer the specified project. Previously, you could select which group to transfer a project to from the dropdown list, which didn’t include groups made available through group sharing. Now, the new endpoint ensures that these groups are included too.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#get-groups-to-which-a-user-can-transfer-a-project) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/371006).

That can help if you have to script moving a project to a group, and need to propose a list of possible targets.